# Use of redundant goals in queries

Tags: prolog, logical-purity

(Upon the [suggestion of @repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282952/multiple-instances-of-prolog-clauses-with-identical-ground-head-any-uses-beside#comment106641078_60282952)) Consider a query of a **pure** program<sup>1</sup> `?- G_0.` What use if any would the query `?- G_0, G_0.` have?

<sup>Footnotes

1 No tabling (to be safe), constraints are OK.

[Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533255/772868) on the subject.</sup>

Comment: Squaring the number of results?

Comment: Promise: 300 bounty

Comment: With the proof tree construction deterministic & identical in both cases? 

Comment: I take it that no state information is preserved from the consecutive running of the goal. In other words a variation of the question is not allowed, e.g. `?- G_0(State), G_0(State).` Also no state is being passed on the stack from the result of the first goal to the second goal?

Comment: `G_0` may be any (pure) goal, including, say `G_0 = append(Xs,Ys,Zs)`

Comment: @GuyCoder: conjunction is required. (With `G_0;G_0` one might test side effects or performance/caching/tabeling issues)

Comment: @David: No requirement in that direction (that is not implied by simple purity)

Comment: @GuyCoder: Hm, not really related

Comment: BTW, instead of `G_0(State),G_0(State)` one rather writes `call(G_1,State), call(G_1,State)`

Comment: No, no recursion. (And please: there is now this chat-warning, so if we continue, this will be moved to chat and thus will be less accessible in the future)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query `?- G_0, G_0.` helps to identify redundant answers of `?- G_0.`

To do so it suffices to compare the number of answers of `?- G_0.` with the number of answers of `?- G_0, G_0.`.  No need to store those answers (which is a frequent source of errors anyway). Just two integers suffice! If they are equal, then there is no redundancy.  But if `?- G_0, G_0.` has more answers, then there is some redundancy.  Here is an example:

```
p(f(_,a)).
p(f(b,_)).

?- p(X).
   X = f(_A, a)
;  X = f(b, _A).  % two answers

?- p(X), p(X).
   X = f(_A, a) 
;  X = f(b, a)
;  X = f(b, a)
;  X = f(b, _A).   % four answers
                   % thus p(X) contains redundancies
```

... and now let's fix this:

```
p(f(B,a)) :-
   dif(B, b).
p(f(b,_)).

?- p(X).
   X = f(_A, a), dif(_A, b)
;  X = f(b, _A).

?- p(X), p(X).
   X = f(_A, a), dif(_A, b), dif(_A, b).
;  X = f(b, _A).    % again two answers, thus no redundancy
```

No need to manually inspect the constraints involved.

This can be further extended when we are explicitly searching for redundant answers only using [`call_nth/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400256/772868).

```
?- G_0, call_nth(G_0, 2).
```

Answer (score 1):

> Consider a query of a pure program1 ?- G_0. What use if any would the query ?- G_0, G_0. have?

I see no usefulness of the second goal, especially when **tail recursion optimization** (**last call optimization**) is **ON**.

I could realize an GC issue (stack/heap overflow)  when the query is resources-greedy and above options are **OFF** (e.g. when debugging).

I think the second call is redundant (for pure program) and should be eliminated by the compiler.